# "echo "password" | sudo -S <command>" asks for password

Tags: linux, terminal, sudo

I trying run a script without become the su user and I use this command for this:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S <command>
```

If I use this command for "scp", "mv", "whoami" commands, the command works very well but when I use for "chmod", the command asks for password for my user. I don't enter password and **the command works**. My problem is the system asks password to me. I don't want the system asks for password.

Problem ss is like this:

```
[myLocalUser@myServer test-dir]$ ls -lt
total 24
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 1397 May 26 12:12 file1
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root  867 May 26 12:12 script1
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 8293 May 26 12:12 file2
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 2521 May 26 12:12 file3

[myLocalUser@myServer test-dir]$ echo "myPassw0rd" | sudo -S chmod 111 /tmp/test-dir/*
[sudo] password for myLocalUser: I DONT WANT ASK FOR PASSWORD

[myLocalUser@myServer test-dir]$ ls -lt
total 24
---x--x--x 1 root root 1397 May 26 12:12 file1
---x--x--x 1 root root  867 May 26 12:12 script1
---x--x--x 1 root root 8293 May 26 12:12 file2
---x--x--x 1 root root 2521 May 26 12:12 file3
```

Comment: I can't tell how to reproduce this. `sudo -S` works a bit badly with programs that ask for input, as their stdin gets connected to the same pipe the password comes from. But `chmod` shouldn't expect input, AFAIK. What does the problematic command do if you open a shell first with `sudo -s`, and then do the `chmod 111 ...` ? Is there some difference compared to other programs that do work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sudoers file, located in /etc/sudoers, to allow specific users execute commands as root without password.

myLocalUser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod

With this line the user myLocalUser can execute chmod as root without a password is needed.

But this also breaks parts of the system security, so be aware not allow too much and fence the task as much as possible.

[sudoers information](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer jar3d but I want the suoders file as same. This is a security problem as you said. I just want use **echo "mypass"...** command without asking password.

Comment: If the commands you want to execute are static, you may can create a shell script with the commands and allow this script in the sudoers, so it is well fenced.

Comment: Actually I will use this command for new servers from remote. These servers are servers of main banking application so I can't change anything in sudoers file. and I wonder the reason, why other commands (like mv, cp) are works very well but chmod asks for password :)

Comment: I can't give "useful vote" for your answer but I will remember when I have 15 rep. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I tried a bit around and noticed that it only appears on the first use (on my Ubuntu 16.04 system). That is a really strange behaviour. But on the first time it doesn't really asks for a password, it is just printing the question and prints a clean bash row directly after the prompt. On the second execution it just executes the command because it has the password from the first time. 
You could suppress this output with 

**echo "password" | sudo -Sp "" <command>**

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -S` prints prompt to `stderr`.

If you don't want to see it, redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`

- The following command redirects stderr at the local host:

```
echo <password> | ssh <server> sudo -S ls 2>/dev/null
```

It is equivalent to `echo <password> | ssh <server> "sudo -S ls" 2>/dev/null`

- The following command redirects stderr at the remote server:

```
echo <password> | ssh <server> "sudo -S ls 2>/dev/null"
```

- If you need to keep `stderr`, but hide `[sudo] password for ...` then you can use process substitution on the local or remote machine. Since `sudo` prompt has no newline, I use `sed` to cut out the `sudo` prompt. I do this to save the first line of `stderr` of the created process.

```sh
# local filtering
echo <password> | ssh <server> "sudo -S ls" 2> >(sed -e 's/^.sudo[^:]\+: //')
#remote filtering
echo <password> | ssh <server> "sudo -S ls 2> >(sed -e 's/^.sudo[^:]\+: //')"
```